# use `pf` to allow TCP traffic on specific port (from specific subnet)

Tags: macos, firewall, pfctl

So, I've read various posts about how to use both the Application Firewall (`apf` or `socketfilterfw`) and the Packet Filter (`pf`) at the same time.  I thought this would be straightfoward since I'm not a `pf` newbie, but perhaps there is something to be learned about `pf`, or if not, about the combination under MacOS.

Essentially, I'm trying to add a `pf` rule that allows (TCP) traffic to a specific port (say `9999`), from a specific subnet (say `192.168.5.0/24`).  Eventually on the Mac, the applciation in question will be a `java` process listening, hence my desire to limit the exposure over just allowing the Application Firewall to accept traffic from anywhere destined for `java`.    In it's place, for experimentation, I'm using netcat (`nc`).

In System Preferences, I've of course enabled the application firewall, turned on ("Enable Stealth Mode"), and ensured that `pf` is enabled.   I then loaded additional rules into `pf`, but I when the application is blocked (`/usr/bin/nc` in this case), it appears as if my pf rules are never used.   A sample transcript to show my current state:

```
mac $ alias apf=/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw
mac $ apf --getglobalstate
Firewall is enabled. (State = 1)
mac $ apf --getstealthmode
Stealth mode enabled
mac $ apf --getappblocked /usr/bin/nc
Incoming connection to /usr/bin/nc is blocked
mac $ sudo pfctl -s info |& grep ^Status
Status: Enabled for 0 days 21:52:31           Debug: Urgent
mac $ sudo pfctl -s rules
pass in quick proto tcp from any to any port = 9999 flags S/SA keep state
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple/*" all
mac $
```

At this point it looks like I should be able to start `nc` listening and connect from another machine, as in:

```
mac $ nc -l 9999

linux $ nc -v -w 1 mac 9999
nc: connect to mac port 9999 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out
```

So, hypotheses and questions:

- `apf` takes precedence over `pf`, in which case, (Q) how do I change or work around that?
- I can't block the application in `apf` **and** allow some ports in via `pf`; see (Q) above.
- `pf` rules are not really interpreted the same way on MacOS as, say, FreeBSD; then: (Q) why not?
- I don't understand enough and I'm really just a newbie, hence, (Q) what don't I know?

Answer (score 1):

> apf takes precedence over pf, in which case, (Q) how do I change or work around that?

It's *not about precedence*; it's logical AND — those firewalls are independent to each other and you're invoking both of them. Even if Pf won't block connections you have specifically verified that `socketfilterfw` won't pass it.